# IPN Simulator does not work on non .com first level domains

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to test using the IPN Simulator and can't get it to work with anything other than **first level .com domain**

Anything like

*domain.co.uk* or
*subdomain.domain.com*

is giving me errors. (We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error.)

This makes it more difficult, as I'm obviously not going to be testing on my live domain.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Stevo

Comment: IPN DEFINITELY works with non-dotcom URLs and sub domains. It also works with paths ending with.html, .php, whatever. As long as the URLs are reachable. It's hard to find what is causing the problem though. Can you try accessing from your browser and see if you get a http 200?

Comment: True, my mistake. My web server did not accept POST, only GET (which is what I tested). I've also tested other domains like http://bbc.co.uk and came to the conclusion above. However it is very poor feedback from paypal, not giving you any details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

My website did not respond **200 on the POST** request.

Only responded 200 on a GET request, which is all I tested. After fixing my web server, all seems fine